# How to define a Key type in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, struct, google-cloud-datastore

I have a user kind:

```
type User struct {
  Username     string
  Email        string
  Password     string
}
```

And a post kind:

```
type Post struct {
  User               // how to define here?
  Title        string
  Content      string
}
```

Post entity looks like:

User: Key(User, '10000')

Title: "some tilte"

Content: "some content"

How can define `Post.User`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Post` entities contain complete `Key`s, use [`datastore.Key`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Key) as the field type:

```
type Post struct {
    User    *datastore.Key
    Title   string
    Content string
}
```